# Popup window doesnt show in Opencv Kivy App

Tags: kivy, opencv3.0

I'm developing an app which  reads a face image, recognizes and want to display a popup with the result. However the code doesnt show the popup.

popup function:

```
def popup_win(status):
    layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)

    label = Label(text="Authenticated") if status else Label(text="Not Identified")
    layout.add_widget(label)



    closeButton = Button(text="OK", font_size=30, background_color=(0, 0, 0, 0))


    layout.add_widget(closeButton)

    # Instantiate the modal popup and display
    popup = Popup(title=' ', content=layout, size_hint=(None, None), size=(150, 150),auto_dismiss=True)

    print("[INFO] Popping UP")
    popup.open()
    popup.dismiss()
    cv2.waitKey(10)

    # Attach close button press with popup.dismiss action
    closeButton.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)

    return
```

### This is where i m calling the function

```
        if proba > 0.8:
            status = "Authenticated"
            #cv2.rectangle(frame, (342, 82), (683, 108), (198, 147, 7), -1)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (345, 85), (680, 105), (255, 255, 255), -1)
            cv2.putText(frame, text4, (350, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.90, (198, 147, 7), 2)
            cv2.normalize(frame, frame, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
            popup_win(status)
```

Comment: It looks like you are calling `popup.dismiss()` immediately after calling `popup.open()`. What happens if you remove the `popup.dismiss()` call?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried that still doesn't show any popup. I added popup.dismiss() to dismiss it manually as per the documentation.   I have also tried dialog boxes however the flow of the opencv camera doesnt stop it continuously keep detecting and recognizing, without showing the popup or the dialog